# HTML5 mobile touch determining size of touch

Tags: html, mobile, touch

I'm looking for some sample HTML5 code on how to determine the shape of a finger that touched a screen.... or some way to measure the size of the finger tap.

Interested in HTML5/javascript/jquery browser-based solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to tell you, but this is simply not possible at this point in time. None of the major browsers support the radius properties of the touch object. You can only get these from a native mobile app.